# Installing OpenBSD on Mac Mini (core i5)

Tags: mac-mini, openbsd

I have a brand new mac mini (core i5). I've yet to install OSX. I'd like to install OpenBSD from a USB drive. I do not want to dual boot, just run OpenBSD.

I used a different machine to transfer the amd64 install52.iso to a USB drive using `dd if=install52.iso of=/dev/disk`. I can mount the USB and the contents look good. However, I can't seem to get the mac mini to boot to the USB drive. Holding `alt` down during boot shows two partitions (one rescue one normal) but not the image on the USB drive. Holding `c` when booting doesn't seem to do anything but delay the boot of the OSX installer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So I think the first problem is `dd` is not creating a bootable image. I put the USB into a windows machine and got "no boot sector" when booting from USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest thing to do: on a 64 bit pc with cd drive put the openbsd install cd and plug the usb flash drive, boot and install on the flash drive as a regular disk. When finished, copy ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.2/amd64/*tgz in the directory /5.2/amd/ on the flash drive. Then plug this flash drive in the mac mini and at the boot prompt type "boot hd0a:/bsd.rd", proceed as usual and when prompted for sets choose "/5.2/amd".
That should work (I don't have any mac), at least it works on any pc/netbook/notebook, let me know plz ;)

Comment: This worked beautifully. bsd.rd runs on the mini great... bsd not so much, there is a kernel panic. Booting "bsd -c" takes you into config mode but the usb keyboard drops out. So it is going to take a bit of work to get this panic reported/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install OpenBSD on the USB flash drive first, just as it's a regular disk install. Using dd just won't work.

Comment: "regular disk install" is a little misleading. You need to burn the iso onto the usb drive and set it as bootable, which is different from "installing" it.

Comment: @MarcusChan so how do I get an ISO onto the USB drive and set it as bootable?

Comment: There are numerous programs and techniques to do this; invariably for me the easiest way is Ubuntu's [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) tool or [UNetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/). I actually haven't seen a foolproof commandline solution yet...